# Hide Repetitive data

Tags: model-view-controller, report, rdlc

I am using `rdlc` to generate my report in MVC. My task is to print a staff schedule. I am using 2 datasets which the first dataset is used for unrepetitive data like `printedBy`, `printedDate` while the second dataset is used for repetitive dataset which is the schedule.I used table in this case.The code works successfully and the data is showed. But i want to do some changes. This the example of current page:

```
7-Mar-2018 8:40 AM - 8:50 AM Ben
7-Mar-2018 8:50 AM - 9:00 AM Yusry
7-Mar-2018 9:10 AM - 9:20 AM Mark
8-Mar-2018 8:40 AM - 8:50 AM Joe
8-Mar-2018 8:50 AM - 8:50 AM Stan
```

I want to it to show like this:

```
7-Mar-2018 8:40 AM - 8:50 AM Ben
           8:50 AM - 9:00 AM Yusry
           9:10 AM - 9:20 AM Mark
8-Mar-2018 8:40 AM - 8:50 AM Joe
           8:50 AM - 8:50 AM Stan
```

What I mean is to hide the date if it is same as before. Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve your desired behaviour you'll need to apply **Grouping**.
I believe it's quite a large subject to explain here. I suggest you take a look at [this official tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/lesson-6-adding-grouping-and-totals-reporting-services).

To get the result from your example, you'll have to add a `Row Group` for the
date part of your `printedDate` field.

If you have any more specific questions about the subject, feel free to leave a comment and I'll be happy to explain further.